# Sum of left join tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my mysql database.
**jobrequest**- jobno, vehicleno
**labour**- date, jobno4, amount2
**materialcost** date, jobno2, amount3
when user select jobno from jobrequest table, I want display total of labourcost and materialcost.....
Here is my code

$result = mysql_query("            SELECT           jobrequest.jobno,jobrequest.vehicleno, SUM(amount2) AS amount2, SUM(amount3) AS amount3,        FROM            jobrequest              LEFT JOIN materialcost              ON jobrequest.jobno = materialused.jobno2                   LEFT JOIN labour                    ON jobrequest.jobno = labour.jobno4         WHERE           ( jobrequest.jobno = '$item1')        ");

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  jobrequest.jobno, jobrequest.vehicleno, 
SUM(amount2) AS amount2, SUM(amount3) AS amount3 FROM  jobrequest 
LEFT JOIN materialcost  ON jobrequest.jobno = materialused.jobno2  
LEFT JOIN labour ON jobrequest.jobno = labour.jobno4 
WHERE  ( jobrequest.jobno = '$item1') 
group by jobrequest.jobno, jobrequest.vehicleno
```

Comment: Its working, answer is amount2 = 32868.539 & amount3 = 19876. But the correct answer is amount2 = 10956.18 & amount3 = 4969.

Comment: have u applied some filtering on date field ?

Comment: his right, if want a date specific dat then apply a filer like : where  (jobrequest.jobno = '$item1' and labour.date= '$item2')

Comment: In labour table has 3 records and materialcost table has 4 records. when calculating total, it becomes 3x4 records....

Comment: jobno   amount2   amount3

Comment: Please, send a script of table with data then i will be help you

Comment: amount2        amount30483         1.68          313o483         1.68          14400483         1.68          32160483         10.5          3130483         10.5          14400483         10.5          3216

Comment: Please, send a sql script for a better understanding'

Comment: Can i join jobrequest table with labour table and jobrequest table with materialcost table seperately.